# Bitcoin rpc getbalance wrong

Tags: json-rpc, balance

I am using v0.11 rpc, In blockchain balance and my rpc balance are different. rpc balance is wrong why?
But transactions are correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "Blockchain balance"? Your full node is your source of truth, don't trust what block explorers or other websites say.

Comment: You should try getbalances instead. I believe that will include your watch-only addresses as well.

Comment: I have deposited some amount of btc and the transaction is confirmed but available balance is low. when i check other source balance is correct.@pinhead

Comment: Ok, I will try getbalances thank you.@Pillagr